How can one say solving one np-complete problem in polynomial proves that all np-complete problems can be solved in p?
I keep reading that we don’t know if p=np or if p!=np , but what is the basis for this universality?
This question is derived from this statement from the book Introduction to algorithms, third edition.
“Second, the set of NP-complete problems has the remarkable property that if an efficient algo- rithm exists for any one of them, then efficient algorithms exist for all of them. “

Keep reading the book?

@orlp cognitive fatigue! I searched online asked around, not helpful so far.

Try searching for the Cook-Levin theorem.

Printed out the paper, reading through it. Looks like the paper also starts from a point of understanding.

Just to make sure: Your ttitle line is completely wrong, because every problem in P is also in NP. But not NP complete.

Write down the definition of NP-complete precisely, and the result is obvious. NP-complete problems are by definition exactly those with that property.

A problem $A$ is NP-complete if every problem in NP is reducible to it in polynomial time. Roughly, given an algorithm for $A$ and a problem $B$ in NP we can turn $A$ into an algorithm for $B$ with only a polynomial blow-up in runtime. Therefore, if we have a polynomial time algorithm for $A$ we get polynomial time algorithms for every problem in NP and so P=NP.
This is the key point of NP-completeness and it is very nice. You should re-visit the definitions until this is obvious to you!
